# If for any reason (,) - comma?

Tags: commas

Dear English native speakers!
Could you please tell me, if a comma is needed in this sentence:

*If for any reason (,) you are not 100 satisfied with the quality of our services, we will refund 100% of your money back.*

As far as my little research on this shows, a comma is not needed, but I’d like to have a feedback from native speakers. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a single comma would be acceptable, as it would separate "If" from the condition making the reduced sentence:

> <strike>[If for any reason,]</strike> you are not 100% satisfied with the quality of our services, we will refund 100% of your money back.

This sentence does not make sense. (I would also add the percent sign after 100).

---

However, if you can use *two* commas and separate the "for" phrase:

> If, for any reason, you are not 100% satisfied with the quality of our services, we will refund 100% of your money back.

However, this version with two commas does not flow as well to me as when reading the sentence with no commas.